# Zero time when previous row = Parked

Tags: t-sql

I need to Calculate the true time of a picking event , the below pulls the scan audits of a picking job , the total time is 18minutes but the true time is 2.09minutes . so i need to 0 the time of the next row after a Park Flag

Any ideas appreciated

```
 Create table #packpark 
( Shipment bigint,
 Shipmentid Nvarchar (20),
 CreatedUser Nvarchar (20),
 TableName Nvarchar (50),
 CreatedDate Datetime ,
 AuditCode Nvarchar (50),
 QtyPicked decimal (13,2),
 SystemType Nvarchar (20)
)

INSERT INTO #packpark
VALUES  

('849975',  '', 'Jon',  'bdt_PickedItems',  '2023-01-26 10:09:00.723',  'Picking Started',  '0.00000',  'S'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:09:28.833',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:09:29.380',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:09:29.910',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:09:43.147',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  '', 'Jon',  'bdt_PickedItems',  '2023-01-26 10:09:48.630',  'Picking Parked',   '0.00000',  'P'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:15:11.587',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:15:12.290',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:15:13.257', '',      '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:15:21.570', '',      '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:15:37.710', '',      '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  '', 'Jon',  'bdt_PickedItems',  '2023-01-26 10:15:43.070',  'Picking Parked',   '0.00000',  'P'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:26:23.343', '',      '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:26:57.907', '',      '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:27:12.780', '',      '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  'SH00216747',   'Jon',  'Picking',  '2023-01-26 10:27:13.657',  '', '1.00000',  'N'),
('849975',  '', 'Jon',  'bdt_PickedItems',  '2023-01-26 10:50:09.320',  'Picking Parked',   '0.00000',  'P')


Select 
Shipment
,ShipmentId
,CreatedUser
,Tablename
,CreatedDate
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(TIME , CreatedDate - LAG(CreatedDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate)))as time_hhmm
,AuditCode
,QtyPicked
,SystemType


from 
#packpark


drop table #packpark
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't share images of output but scripts to generate testdata.

Comment: edited and changed to sample date

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this, or would you like to see a summation of the total duration?

```
SELECT
     Shipment,
     Shipmentid,
     CreatedUser,
     TableName,
     CreatedDate,
     CASE WHEN LAG(AuditCode) OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate) = 'Picking Parked' THEN
             '00:00:00.000000'
          ELSE
             CONVERT(
                       VARCHAR(15),
                       CONVERT(
                                 TIME,
                                 CreatedDate
                                 - LAG(CreatedDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate)
                              )
                    )
     END AS time_hhmm,
     AuditCode,
     QtyPicked,
     SystemType
FROM #packpark;
```

Comment: looks promising , just running it through a larger dataset

Comment: Worked brilliantly , now silly question ifs there a way to tie the lag to the Shipment only because if i run the query for a date range it Lags from the previous date of the previous shipment . ? The only option i can think of at the moment is to loop each shipment in the range into another temp table ? any better ideas ?

Comment: Add partition by shipment in the lag parts

Comment: I'm such a doughnut , Partition over was most defiantly the answer :)